# How to split a big view component on many small components in nextjs?

Tags: next.js

As you know in nextjs for routing we have to use folder structure.
But what should I do if I have a big view component and I want to split it on many small components in different files? And in the same time hide them from external requests.
The same problem I see with css (css in js - styled-components) files. It would be convenient to have them nearby its component.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with React here so there's many opinions on how to structure your application.

Personally, I go with creating "Page" components under the Pages directory. Within these components I'll usually do stuff like check for required authentication or other "meta" things.

This means I can halt rendering, handle clientside redirects, and so on before content lands on the page.

`pages/about.jsx`

```js
function AboutPage() {
 const loggedIn = useLoggedIn();

 if (!loggedIn) return null;

 return <AboutWrapper />
}
```

I'll start constructing the "view" of the page within what I call the wrapper:

`components/AboutWrapper/index.jsx`

```js
const Title = styled.h1`
  font-weight: strong;
`;

function AboutWrapper() {
 return
     <div>
        <Title>About page</Title>
        <HeroCarousel />
     </div>
}
```

Keep in mind that even though stuff in the wrapper won't be rendered if you stop it from being rendered in the Page component, that you're still delivering JS so don't put any sensitive information directly into these files - request those from your back-end. (Or NextJS's api directory)

If the view is massive, I'll make sure to have commonly used parts of the page are in their own file in the components directory:

`components/HeroCarousel/index.jsx`

```js
const Container = styled.div`
 background-color: #F2F2F2;
`;

function HeroCarousel() {
 return
     <Container>
        <img src="" />
        <img src="" />
        <img src="" />
     </Container>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to do it like this.
Leave the folder "pages" only for routing and keep all components and styles in a folder "views" which will lie next to the folder "pages".

[image]